# Why I can't use Function.prototype.call on an array of functions with forEach?

Tags: javascript

I would like to execute all functions in an array in global scope. I want to use a shorthand so I decided to use `Function.prototype.call` and `call` `Function.prototype`'s `call` method on all functions. I don't care about the arguments `forEach` sends to the functions.

```
[function(){}, function(){}].forEach(Function.prototype.call.call)
```

Why this is not working and throwing following error?

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 5):

You want:

```
[function(){}, function(){}]
  .forEach(Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.call))
```

But you can simplify a bit using the `Function` constructor which already gives you `call`:

```
.forEach(Function.call.bind(Function.call))
```

Comment: aside: Function.call === Function.prototype.call; (since inheritance works)

Answer (score 0):

> Why this is not working and throwing following error?

The internal call looks something similar to

```
Function.prototype.call.call.apply(undefined, function() {}, 0, [])
                                     ^--- it's `undefined` here because you haven't
                                          specified anything explicitly
                                          as a 2nd `forEach` arg
```

And internally `call` expects that its `this` will point to the correct function (`Function.prototype.call` in this case), whereas "you" are passing `undefined`

So technically this code works as expected:

```
[
    function(){console.log(1)},
    function(){console.log(2)}
]
    .forEach(Function.prototype.call.call, Function.prototype.call)
```

But the elclanrs' solution with `bind` is better

Comment: Oh, I was adding this to my answer from your comments, I'll upvote then.

Comment: [`Function` can be overriden, in that case your code won't work. -1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17245542/633183)

Comment: @naomik: I **NEVER EVER** mentioned my solutions are ideal and take into account everything. Stop being a kid.